# APOC: unavailable namespaces

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Just added apoc to a neo4j installation. As a result, got access to the namespaces apoc.coll and apoc.load **only**. Can't even do basic stuff like RETURN apoc.version().

The jar in the plugins directory contains much more than that, but in the localhost browser, **I can't see anything but the above**. Both apoc and neo4j version 3.3.

Before editing the config file, apoc was totally unavailable. Additions to config:

```
    dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
    dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.algo.*,apoc.atomic.*
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.algo.*,apoc.atomic.*

    dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.meta.*
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.meta.*
    dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
    apoc.trigger.enabled=true
    apoc.ttl.enabled=true
    apoc.ttl.schedule=5
    apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true
    apoc.import.file.enabled=true
    apoc.export.file.enabled=true
    # apoc.jdbc.<key>.uri=jdbc-url-with-credentials
    # apoc.es.<key>.uri=es-url-with-credentials
    # apoc.mongodb.<key>.uri=mongodb-url-with-credentials
    # apoc.couchbase.<key>.uri=couchbase-url-with-credentials
    apoc.jobs.scheduled.num_threads=number-of-threads
    apoc.jobs.default.num_threads=number-of-threads
```

I added 'algo' and 'atomic' as an experiment, as I was thinking that I could see 'load' and 'coll' simply because they were declared in the config. But no - didn't help.

Restarted neo4j and rebooted the machine repeatedly.

Comment: Your config file contains multiple `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist` & `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted`, and Neo4j will only 'read' the first one. Can you try to concatenate them into one property and restart your server ?

Comment: Yes, an amazingly simple solution. My bad.